# Vector dimensionality inference

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

If $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are vectors such that:

$\vec{u}$ . $\vec{v}$ $\neq 0$

$\vec{u}$ . $\vec{w}$ $\neq 0$

$\vec{v}$ . $\vec{w}$ $\neq 0$

**What can be said about the dimensionality of the vector space to which they belong?**

The above means they do not form an orthogonal base so we cannot express the full space using just $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$. But the question would imply more of an answer than this.

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need an orthogonal set to span a space. In fact, if your vector space does not have an inner product, you don't even have the concept of orthogonality, yet you still have bases.

As an example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual inner product, the vectors $$ u=(1,0,0),\ v=(1,1,0),\ w=(1,1,1) $$ are not orthogonal at all, yet they span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: The only thing you can say is that the dimension of the space is $\geq 1$. For instance: $\mathbf u=\mathbf v=\mathbf w\neq \mathbf 0$.

Comment: Just to add to Farnight's comment: in the worst case you would have $\bf u, v$ and $\bf w$ collinear.